# Automatic scrolling in textview in ios 4.3 + iphone sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, textview, ios4

automatic scroll occurs in ios 4.3 , when textViewShouldBeginEditing method call.
I want to stop this automatic scrolling.
currently scroll goes upside.

Comment: Not clear about your problem. Could you explain more details, paste code or give some screen shot.

Comment: textview.text = @"";
When I start to write in textview, It automatically scrolls upside.
but there is no need to auto-scroll in textview.
Because textview height is enough for one line.

I want to stop that auto-scroll in textview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[txtview scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, txtview.contentSize.height-txtview.frame.size.height, txtview.frame.size.width, txtview.frame.size.height) animated:NO];
```

set this frame in textview begin editing.
And set y position of textview  txtview.contentSize.height-txtview.frame.size.height
in textview should change in characters.

It works..

Answer (score 1):

The code below is cleaner and works better:

```
[yourTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(self.text.length, 0)];
```

In Swift 2.2:

```
yourTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location: yourTextView.text.length, length: selectedRange.length))
```